# android studio project compiled in 2.2p1 strange borders

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded android studio to 2.2.p1 and builded my project without errors. There are some strange borders around views (see att). When I create the new default project and build it in 2.2.p1 the problem is the same. When I do the same in 2.1.1 the app behaviour is normal - without borders. The problem is, that I'm not able to find the cause of this behaviour and build my existing project in 2.1.1 did not help -> there is something "strange" in existing project which was already compiled in 2.2p1. Do you have a idea and solution for this?

thank you for your time and help ... noe

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210467

I think this is correlated to the bug that is filed.

So long story short, just wait for the fix, OR, downgrade your gradle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.+'
```